# ConfigureAwait(false) not making HttpContext NULL as expected

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, async-await

When using `async/await`, to avoid deadlocks, it is recommended to use `ConfigureAwait(false)` to all the way down to the last layer. I understand that using `ConfigureAwait(false)` will also make the current HttpContext null. [Article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx)

Below is the sample code just to understand why `ConfigureAwait(false)` is not making HttpContext NULL when expected, and making it NULL when it is NOT expected.

**Controller**

```
public class MyController : Controller
{
    private readonly MyService _service = new MyService();
    private readonly MyMapper _mapper = new MyMapper();        


    public async Task<ActionResult> DoSomething()
    {
        var data = await _service.GetData().ConfigureAwait(false);

        // EXPECTED: Below, HttpContext should NOT NULL
        // ACTUAL: HttpContext is NOT NULL as expected
        if (HttpContext == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("context");
        }

        var model = _mapper.Map(data);

        return View(model);
    }
}
```

**A Service that makes async call to datasource to GetData**

```
public class MyService
{
    public async Task<string> GetData()
    {
        // EXPECTED: HttpContext should be NULL here since we are calling 
        //this method from the Controller with ConfigureAwait(false)     

        // ACTUAL: HttpContext is NOT NULL, WHY?
        if(HttpContext.Current == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("context");
        }

        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            var response = await client.GetAsync("http://url").ConfigureAwait(false);
            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
            return await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
        }
    }
}
```

**A mapper class maps the data to model**

```
public class MyMapper
{
    public MyModel Map(string data)
    {
        // EXPECTED:  HttpContext should NOT NULL here since async call is already done.
        // ACTUAL: HttpContext is NULL here. WHY?
        if (HttpContext.Current == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("context");
        };

        return new MyModel()
        {
            Message = data
        };
    }
}
```

The HttpContext is expected to be NULL inside `MyService` and expected to be NOT NULL inside `MyMapper`, but that is not the case. Please see my inline comments inside `MyService` and `MyMapper`

Answer (score 10):

You have it backwards. `HttpContext.Current` will be null *after* the context switch, not before.

So:

```
// ACTUAL: HttpContext is NOT NULL, WHY?
if(HttpContext.Current == null)
{
    throw new ArgumentNullException("context");
}
```

No, it is *expected* to be not `null` since there hasn't been any `await` so far (the parent `await` does not apply).

```
// EXPECTED:  HttpContext should NOT NULL here since async call is already done.
// ACTUAL: HttpContext is NULL here. WHY?
if (HttpContext.Current == null)
```

The switch happened after this line

```
var response = await client.GetAsync("http://url").ConfigureAwait(false);
```

So it is expected for it to be `null`.

Comment: In the controller action method, `AFTER` the service call `_service.GetData(...)` i am checking HttpContext twice, 1> in the action method 2>in the mapper. If the HttpContext is expected to be null in the mapper ( as you mentioned) then it should be null in action method as well (but in the action method HttpContext is not null and then it becomes NULL in the mapper.).

Comment: @LP13 One thing is the `Controller.HttpContext` property, which is populated when the controller is created. Another thing is the `HttpContext.Current` static property, which is the same as `Controller.HttpContext` before a context switch

Comment: but shouldn't HttpContext.Current get populated after the async call is done?

Comment: @LP13 Nope, because that runs on another thread where it wasn't populated. This is basically why `HttpContext.Current` was an extremely bad idea and doesn't exist on ASP.NET Core