# Why do I have a filled HttpContext when COnfigureAwait(false) is used?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, async-await

First of all, I've seen this question: [ConfigureAwait(false) not making HttpContext NULL as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49780873/configureawaitfalse-not-making-httpcontext-null-as-expected) but I still can't explain what's happening.

Here I have two methods:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Contact2()
{
    var h = new HttpClient();
    var sc = SynchronizationContext.Current;
    HttpContext.Session["x"] = "d";

    var s = await h.GetStringAsync("http://www.google.com").ConfigureAwait(false);

    var contextIsNull = HttpContext == null;
    return View();
}

public async Task<ActionResult> Contact()
{
    var h = new HttpClient();
    var sc = SynchronizationContext.Current;
    HttpContext.Session["x"] = "d";

    await Task.Delay(2000).ConfigureAwait(false);

    var contextIsNull = HttpContext == null;

    return View();
}
```

When executing both of them the `SynchronizationContext.Current` is null as expected, but `HttpContext` is not null and in both situations I have access to `Session`. Why is this? Why isn't `HttpContext` not null? The context has been switched because I read `HttpContext` after await, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`HttpContext.Current` is `null`, not `Controller.HttpContext`.

`await` doesn't change the values of any of your local or member variables.

Note that just because you *can* access it doesn't mean you *should*. `HttpContext` is not threadsafe.