# Does ConfigureAwait(false) triggers another thread from ThreadPool?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asynchronous, async-await, threadpool

Well, I'm a little bit confused. I provided example bellow.
Let's assume that we have .NET framework MVC application for this example:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private int _someFiled = 0;

    public async Task<string> Get()
    {
        var context = System.Web.HttpContext.Current;
        _someFiled = 5;

        var jsonTask = await GetJsonAsync(
            new Uri("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos"));
        return jsonTask;
    }

    public async Task<string> GetJsonAsync(Uri uri)
    {   
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            var jsonString = await client.GetStringAsync(uri).ConfigureAwait(false);

            var context = System.Web.HttpContext.Current;
            var value = _someFiled;

            return jsonString;
        }
    }
}
```

At start of the `Get` action, you can see that assigned context variable with `System.Web.HttpContext.Current` and `_someField` with 5.
In `GetJsonAsync` method I use `ConfigureAwait`. As I know after `ConfigureAwait` continuation behavior of `GetJsonAsync` does not resume on the context thread. Instead `GetJsonAsync` will resume on a `ThreadPool` thread.
And so as it runs in different thread context will be null under `GetJsonAsync` method, but `_someField` remains 5 still. My question is after `ConfigureAwait(false)` statement why `System.Web.HttpContext.Current` is null and `_someField` remains same as it was before?

Comment: Why do you expect an instance field of a class to be different for each thread that accesses it? That does not happen unless you specifically [make it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7850913/11683).

Comment: @GSerg well I thought as HttpContext.Current state changed to null, same should happen with_someField filed

Comment: What do you want to actuslly achieve, (might be an easier place to start)?

Comment: `HttpContext.Current` is not your property, it's `HttpContext`'s property, and it becomes null because it is [expected to](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49780873/11683), not because all properties have different values per thread.

Comment: `ConfigureAwait()` doesn't trigger any threads. It says that `await` doesn't have to return to the original sync context - the UI thread in desktop applications or the request context in ASP.NET Old. Console and ASP.NET Core applications have no sync context so `ConfigureAwait(false)` has no effect. `ConfigureAwait(false)` is meant for library code, not as a `go-fast` switch that's used everywhere

Comment: In ASP.NET Old though `HttpContext.Current` *depends* on the sync context. When you use `ConfigureAwait(false)` execution *won't* go back to the original context and `HttpContext.Current` won't have anything to return. To fix this *remove* `ConfigureAwait(false)`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos  after ConfigureAwait(false) continuation will not be invoked in new thread from thread pool?

Comment: @west no, it will be invoked in the same threadpool thread as the async operation. In that thread there's no current request and hence, HttpContext. `ConfigureAwait(false)` doesn't say "run on a different thread" or "don't block". It means "don't do anything special after await, let the root caller decide". If you want access to the request context you'll have to pass it as a parameter. Or just not use `ConfigureAwait(false)`

Comment: @west `ConfigureAwait(false)` is used in libraries because it doesn't force a context switch. The library author has no idea how their library is going to be used - a desktop app? A web app? Console? Would a common `await` cause blocking because the UI thread itself is busy? There's no way to tell. The actual application code on the other hand *does* know what's going on. The app developer (in this case you) should avoid using `ConfigureAwait(false)` unless it's really needed. Otherwise the code will keep running on a background thread, as it did in your case

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos at the beginning when request is received, this request is not invoked thread(context thread)? And after ConfigureAwait(false) same context thread is processing this request?

Comment: Again, `ConfigureAwait(false)` doesn't execute anything itself. It modifies how `await` behaves. After `await client.GetStringAsync(uri).ConfigureAwait(false);` execution remains in the threadpool thread, where there's no request HttpContext. Just remove `ConfigureAwait(false)` if you really want to use the context there. On the other hand, why not *pass* the context instance as a parameter?

Comment: Is the *real* problem that `GetJsonAsync()` blocked without that `ConfigureAwait(false)`? You can keep using `ConfigureAwait(false)` if you pass any data you need as parameters instead of trying to access the static HttpContext instance

Comment: Actually I wanted to get into details how it is works. While reading this blogpost https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html. There is deadlock example and said after ConfigureAwait does not resume on context thread instead it resume on other thread which is released from the thread pool

Comment: @west that thread can be the same thread that executed the asynchronous operation. It's cheaper to use that thread instead of starting another one.